# how to use UnboundID LDAP in android?

Tags: java, android, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I want use LDAP(Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) in android.But i have no idea about LDAP. I have seen following link:

[Neil's LDAP SDK post](http://www.dirmgr.com/blog/2009/3/24/using-ldap-on-android.html)

`He told like` android developers don't need to worry about missing LDAP support for Android because the `UnboundID LDAP SDK` for Java works just fine on the Android platform. I've done quite a bit of testing and made sure that things just work. With a couple of exceptions (primarily CRAM-MD5, DIGEST-MD5, and GSSAPI, which require the Java SASL API that isn't available on Android) pretty much all of the functionality that we offer in our LDAP SDK can be used on Android

Note that there is no special "Android" version of the LDAP SDK -- the same SDK that you can use for writing desktop clients or server-side applications works without any changes on the Android platform.

How to use UnboundID LDAP SDK in android.Please any one provide tutorial or some example.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LDAP SDK also includes an example Android app, in the android-ldap-client directory.

Answer (score 0):

DanielWeisser already did that. The project is on GIT, you can modify source if you let the credentials. https://github.com/weisserd/LDAP-Sync

He used the UnboundID LDAP Librairy  to make this.

Good luck.