# Android LDAP authentication (UniboundID)

Tags: android, authentication, ldap

I haven't found any samples or turtorials on how to do it so I'm asking here, for a native android app I need the user to login using his SamAccountName and password. First I need to check wether the user exists and then query wether he is inside a group so that he has the rights to use the app.

If any of you guys have sample code or a guide on how to do it would be appreciated.
I'm using android studio 2.3 with gradle 3.3.

Edit the basic thing I want to do is authenticate make sure the credentials of the user are ok then proceed to my mainactivity, I'm also new to active directory in general so any help regarding android and LDAP authentication is welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use UnboundID LDAP in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719872/how-to-use-unboundid-ldap-in-android)

Comment: I already saw that post but it doesn't explain how to use implement it, and I don't get any wiser from the sorcecode from the project.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 : Download the UNBOUNDID from github or from here [here](https://github.com/pingidentity/ldapsdk/releases).

STEP 2 : AFTER DOWNLOADING EXTRACT THE CONTENT.

STEP 3 : OPEN THAT FOLDER AND COPY JAR HAVING NAME **unboundid-ldapsdk.jar**.

STEP 4 : Open your android project and paste it inside the lib folder just like in the screen shot.

[image]

STEP 5 : Now right click the jar file and at the bottom there is a option Add Library.

STEP 6 : You are done enjoy using the library's functions and methods.
also you can take a reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801282/connect-android-to-openldap-server/38207717?noredirect=1#comment63840595_38207717).